# Windows fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, curl, g++

Решил попробовать сделать в Windows простенькую программку для скачивания файла, которая без проблем работает в Ubuntu. Там, кажется, все есть по умолчанию, надо только установить пакеты libcurl-dev и libcurl-openssl1.0-dev. А тут... Настроил g++ по [этой инструкции](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/1.2.php) . "Hello world" вроде бы компилится... И все, встрял. Вот код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

int main(void) {
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
const char *url = "https://update.madmentat.ru/test.tar.xz";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "test.tar.xz";
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
    system("tar -zxvf test.tar.xz");
    system("del test.tar.xz");
  //system("test.exe");
}
return 0;
}
```

Команда компиляции такая:

> g++ update.cpp -lcurl -o updete

Однако же, каждый раз получаю ответ

> update.cpp:4:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
> 4 | #include <curl/curl.h>
> |
> compilation terminated.

Пожалуйста, опишите последовательность дальнейших действий, чтобы заставить это заработать, чтобы было понятно новичку, без лишней воды и т. д.

Допустим, я скачал библиотеку с https://curl.se/windows/
Распаковал в C:\curl
А дальше что?

Забегая наперед, признаюсь, что мне как-то удалось на работе скомпилировать этот код и программа даже заработала, но из-за того что я перепробовал сто разных вариантов - и так, и эдак - в голове образовалась какая-то каша, и теперь я не могу повторить то же самое дома... Но... Это еще полбеды. Скомпилировав программу на работе и запустив ее на соседнем компе со свеже-установленной Виндой, я почему-то получил ошибку, мол, не хватает libcurl-4.dll. Интересно, почему?

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать все нужные `.dll` в директорию с исполняемым файлом на соседнем компе.

Comment: Так я попробовал уже, все глухо. Не качает. Если их не положить, то программа ругается, мол, нужна такая-то библиотека, эта и та, а если их положить то программа отрабатывает глухо, ничего не происходит. Причем, что интересно, на том же компе, где она компилируется - все работает как надо.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, ломал голову, страдал, да так ничего толком и не добился, но... Изначально у меня была задача, состоящая, грубо говоря, из 4 пунктов: скачать архив, распаковать архив, удалить скачанный архив и запустить бинарник. И вот, наконец-то, меня осенило! Я надеюсь, мой опыт окажется кому-нибудь полезным. Смотрите, в чем дело... curl поставляетя в 2-х видах. Первый - это типа библиотеки, исходники и прочая мутотень для нердов с запотевшими очками, а второй - это готовый пакет, который вшит по умолчанию практически везде, в любые современные операционные системы, т. е., для данной задачи не обязательно компостировать себе мозги - чтобы скачать файл, надо просто вызвать curl через system() - и все!

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
system("echo Starting to download madcalc.windows.zip");
system("curl https://update.madmentat.ru/madcalc.windows.zip --output madcalc.windows.zip");
system("tar -xf madcalc.windows.zip");
system("del madcalc.windows.zip");
system("madCalc.exe");
}
```

Comment: Так а зачем C++ программа тогда? Можно просто `.bat`-скрипт сделать или ввести эти команды вручную в консоли.

Comment: В принципе да, можно и батник. Но иногда лучше спрятать все это в файлик, который не прочитаешь блокнотом. Конечно, вопрос все еще остается открытым, мне до сих пор интересно, почему эта библиотека так странно себя ведет. Я тут ставлю на работе эксперименты... Вроде все скомпилил без ошибок, кинул на соседний комп, запускаю - и ничего! Не качает, хоть ты тресни. Хотя на том компе, где компилил - все работает без нареканий. Я не понимаю почему, уже устал над этим голову ломать.